# How to solve specific task with optimal allocation between values in two data frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

Solve this task:
There are teams with a fixed number of open positions. These teams may have employees in different cities. We also have a certain number of candidates for certain types of positions in different cities. It is necessary to distribute these candidates among the teams in such a way that the teams have as many employees as possible in the same city. We cannot change the city of the candidate.

Example:

input:
team data:

```
    team_id              position      
     0.0                 Manager 
     0.0                 Manager
     0.0                 Engineer
     1.0                 Engineer
     1.0                 Engineer
     2.0                 Engineer
     2.0                 Engineer
     2.0                 Manager
```

candidates data:

```
    candidate_id                     position            city
             1                       Manager           New York
             2                       Manager         San Francisco
             3                        Engineer         Boston
             4                        Engineer         Boston
             5                        Engineer         London
             6                         Engineer        London
             7                         Manager         New York
             8                        Engineer         Paris
```

output:

```
    employee_id    team_id       position        city
             1        0.0        Manager        New York
             7        0.0        Manager        New York
             3        0.0        Engineer       Boston
             4        1.0        Engineer       Boston
             8        1.0        Engineer       Paris
             5        2.0        Engineer       London
             6        2.0        Engineer       London
             2        2.0        Manager        San Francisco
```

How could I do that? I tried this:

```
def allocate_candidates(teams, candidates):
    city_pos_candidates = {}
    for candidate in candidates:
        city = candidate[2]
        pos = candidate[1]
        if city not in city_pos_candidates:
            city_pos_candidates[city] = {}
        if pos not in city_pos_candidates[city]:
            city_pos_candidates[city][pos] = []
        city_pos_candidates[city][pos].append(candidate)

    employee_id = 0
    output = []
    for team in teams:
        pos = team[1]
        for city, positions in city_pos_candidates.items():
            if pos in positions:
                candidate = positions[pos].pop(0)
                output.append((employee_id, team[0], pos, city, candidate[0]))
                employee_id += 1
                if not positions[pos]:
                    del positions[pos]
                if not city_pos_candidates[city]:
                    del city_pos_candidates[city]
                break
    return output

team_data = [    (0.0, "Manager"),    (0.0, "Manager"), (0.0, "Engineer"),    (1.0, "Engineer"),    (1.0, "Engineer"),    (2.0, "Engineer"),    (2.0, "Engineer"),    (2.0, "Manager"),]
candidate_data = [    (1, "Manager", "New York"),    (2, "Manager", "San Francisco"),    (3, "Engineer", "Boston"),    (4, "Engineer", "Boston"),    (5, "Engineer", "London"),    (6, "Engineer", "London"),    (7, "Manager", "New York"), (8, "Engineer", "Paris")]
```

but the output is wrong:

```
[(0, 0.0, 'Manager', 'New York', 1),
 (1, 0.0, 'Manager', 'New York', 7),
 (2, 0.0, 'Engineer', 'Boston', 3),
 (3, 1.0, 'Engineer', 'Boston', 4),
 (4, 1.0, 'Engineer', 'London', 5),
 (5, 2.0, 'Engineer', 'London', 6),
 (6, 2.0, 'Engineer', 'Paris', 8),
 (7, 2.0, 'Manager', 'San Francisco', 2)]
```

as can be seen, it would be more optimal if engineer from Paris is in team 1.0 and employee engineer from London in team 2.0